# No aplicar filtro o segmentacion a columna de matriz en power bi

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

Buen día compañeros, estoy haciendo un dashboard en POWER BI y necesito a una matriz por ejemplo como muestro en la imagen a las columnas de cantidad total y valor total no se le aplique el filtro de fecha, y a las otras columnas si se le aplique, como podría hacer eso.
Gracias espero su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Antony. Ya llevas dos años en el sitio. Ya deberías saber [cómo se escribe una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que definir dos medidas con DAX:

```
Valor = SUM(tabla[valor])
Valor total = CALCULATE(SUM(tabla[valor]), ALL(Fechas))
```

La primera medida es sensible al filtro de fechas, mientras que la segunda no lo es. Debes cambiar el nombre de los objetos: tabla por tu tabla, valor por la columna que representa el valor y fechas por el nombre de tu tabla de fechas.